in Firefox querySelector with attribute while finding path in svg gives error
My code is working well in Chrome but not in Firefox.
When I search path element using querySelector with attribute Firefox gives an error that path is not found.
defs.appendChild(svgGradient);
const path = this.#svg.querySelector(`[ElementName="${this.#name}"]`);
path.setAttribute("fill", `url(#${gradientId})`);

When I searched the path with id I was able to find the path. So I suspect the in Firefox query with attribute tag is not support or have I made a mistake, can anyone correct me?
Below is the error I get
Uncaught TypeError: path is null
    fillGradient texture.js:144
    Texture texture.js:60
    emit events.js:153
    setListeners gradient.js:207
texture.js:144

this.#svg contains svg markup and #name is identifier for selected part.

What exactly is the error in the Firefox console? What debugging have you done? Step through your code with the debugger and check the values of this.#svg and this.#name

@Phil this.#svg and this.#name are not the reason for error.

Running a quick test, I found that both Chrome and Firefox are interpreting the attribute as lowercase elementname.


console.log(document.querySelector('svg').innerHTML);
<svg><path ElementName="foo" /></svg>



While Chrome is able to query the element using any case, Firefox requires a strict match


const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
['ElementName', 'elementname', 'ElEmEnTnAmE'].forEach((attr) => {
  console.log(attr, svg.querySelector(`[${attr}]`) !== null);
});
<svg><path ElementName="foo" /></svg>



In Chrome, these are all true but Firefox only matches elementname.
I would recommend normalising your custom attributes to lowercase / kebab-case, eg
<path element-name="foo" />


I applied the changes and now code is working fine Chrome and Firefox. Thanks.
